# Can I use two of these modules to charge two lithium-ion cells that are in series?

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

I need a solution to charge two 3.7 V lithium-ion cells that are in series. However I have a very limited access to modules and I need to have current limitation as my source won't stand beyond 0.5 A.

I have this module available (TP4056 based), but it's for a single cell. Is there any way to make two of these modules do the job?

[image]

Datasheet: [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf)

Comment: We will probably need more than a picture of a PCB to tell. Please link the datasheet to the BMS.

Comment: Almost certainly not. There don't appear to be any transformer-type isolation components on there. Unless you power each from a separate 5 V wall-wart.

Comment: You can **IF** the input to each charger board is isolated (floating). Each battery will then be dealt with separately. || A usually less desirable way is to transfer the charger between batteries as needed - eg using a DPDT relay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If you try, **KABOOM!**

That's because they are not isolated. Upon connection, they make a short circuit across one Li-ion cell.

> Is there any way to make two of these modules do the job?

Yes, but it's more expensive than buying the correct charger. It involves adding an isolated DC-DC converter between the USB port and one of the charger modules.

Comment: Or simply using two isolated chargers.